# How to shorten/optimize this function while staying ESlint compliant (always-return)

Tags: javascript, function, promise, return, eslint

I am having trouble getting this function to comply with ESlint regulations but not "looking" stupid (returning where no return should be needed). Which leads me to think I am doing something wrong or not understanding something about promises.

I tried the function in the following way

This is accepted:

```
    let getDoc = fb.db.collection("characters");
    let char = new character();
    let query = getDoc
      .where("name", "==", name)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log("No matching documents.");
          return promise.reject(err);
        } else {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
          char.id = doc.id;
          char.name = doc.data().name;
          char.type = doc.data().type;
          return char;
        });}
        return char;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error getting documents", err);
        return "Error getting documents", err;
      });
    return query;     
  }

This is not:

read(name) {
    let getDoc = fb.db.collection("characters");
    let char = new character();
    let query = getDoc
      .where("name", "==", name)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log("No matching documents.");
          return promise.reject(err);
        }

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
          char.id = doc.id;
          char.name = doc.data().name;
          char.type = doc.data().type;
          return char;
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error getting documents", err);
        return "Error getting documents", err;
      });
    ## tried with and without return query here ##
  }

I expected there to not to be a warning from ESlint regarding a missing return, as the function should always return either an error (No such document) or a character (char).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example you never return "char" in your `.then()` block. The `return char;` inside your loop returns a value for the function you passed to forEach, not the then block. In fact your whole forEach loop isn't doing anything at all.

```
.then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log("No matching documents.");
      return promise.reject(err); // <-- Return error
    }

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
      char.id = doc.id;
      char.name = doc.data().name;
      char.type = doc.data().type;
      return char; // <--- This return is for the forEach function
    });

    return char; // <----- Added return here
})
```

I don't think this code will do what you want though. This will return the last value of char from the loop.

If you intended to modify the values inside of snapshot, you should use `map` instead of `forEach`.

```
.then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log("No matching documents.");
      return promise.reject(err); // <-- Return error
    }

    // Convert array of docs to array of Characters 
    snapshot = snapshot.map(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
      let c = new Character();
      c.name = doc.data().name;
      c.type = doc.data().type;
      return c;
    });

    return snapshot; // <---- return converted array
})
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Maybe let me explain what I am trying to do here. I have number of documents that could have the name "Alex". I would like to return all characters (read documents) and their values (read fields) where the name field = "Alex".

So I filter `.where("name", "==", name)`.

My question would now be: How do I return all documents as one array/object with all character-objects (A class I definied with `this.name, this.type and this.id`) inside, so I can loop through them and acces the properties (this.type for example)?

I thought looping through (`snapshot.forEach`) is the way?

Comment: @RobSteward Use the second block of code. You may need to modify the `let c= new Character()` line to use your constructor properly. That code will return an array of all the characters from the "documents" you fetched. Look at [JS Array Map Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to see how this code works to convert the array of documents to an array of characters